# Vue router-link doesn't work within b-table

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Based on the following tutorial:
https://youtu.be/4deVCNJq3qc?t=7710

Question> I am able to show the table as expected. However, the table column name doesn't show a hyper-link. What should I do to fix the issue?

Thank you

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.11.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
    "vuex": "^3.1.3"
  },



<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Cats for Adoption</h1>

    <b-table striped hover :items="cats">
      <template slot="name" slot-scope="data">
        <router-link :to="`/pets/${data.value}`">{{ data.value }}</router-link>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import cats from "@/data/cats";

export default {
  data() {
    return { cats: cats };
  }
};
</script>

# /data/cats.js
export default [
  {
    name: "Fish",
    breed: "tuxedo",
    species: "cat",
    gender: "male",
    age: 20,
    color: "black/white",
    weight: 13,
    location: "fourside",
    notes: "Sweet kitty. He loves getting his belly rubbed."
  }
];
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What html is rendered?

Comment: @StevenB. I updated the rendered html. please check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap-Vue appears to have changed the way you do custom data rendering.  Your template should be:

```
<b-table striped hover :items="cats">
  <template v-slot:cell(name)="data">
    <router-link :to="`/pets/${data.value}`">{{ data.value }}</router-link>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-mccarthy-6qr74?file=/src/components/Pets.vue)

Comment: For reference on table slot name changes, see the change log for changes from the rc releases to the v2.x stable releases: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/misc/changelog#breaking-changes-and-deprecated-features-removal-v200